# Testing if a block is executed with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, xctest, ocmock

I'm using `OCMock` and `XCTest` to test a method which takes a block as an argument. I want to test that the block is executed both on success and failure. Would the code below be enough to test that the block has been executed?

```
__block  BOOL didExecute = NO;

[testSubject performActionWithBlock:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    didExecute = YES;
}];

XCTAssertTrue(didExecute);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that a block has been executed, the best way in Xcode 6 is to use [`XCTestExpectation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_3_writing_test_classes/testing_3_writing_test_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW6):

```
// Create an expectation with whatever description you want
// The description will be displayed in the test report if the expectation causes the test to fail
XCTestExpectation *blockExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Block Expectation"];

[testSubject performActionWithBlock:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    // Inside the block, fulfill the expectation
    [blockExpectation fulfill];
}];

// The timeout should be the max amount of time you want the test to wait
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1.0 handler:nil];
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize this was introduced in Xcode 6.